# Angular routing: set the parent component to load first, and load the child component second

Tags: angular

i got a problem while using angular routing, this is the routing:

```
  {
    path: 'parent',
    component: ParentComponent,
    children: [
      {
          { path: 'child1', component: Child1Component },
          { path: 'child2', component: Child2Component }
      }
    ]    
  },
```

I'm using JWT that last 10 sec with refresh token that last 1 day, when i refresh the page, the moment 10 second pass, angular will fire a "refresh" request, but when 2(or more) components run the APIs, it both detect that token is expire and BOTH fire the "refresh" request to the back end, and that is the problem, i only want 1 "refresh" request sent, so i'm thinking of just limit the flow of components that run, instead of both components run, if one of them run one after one(synchronously), problem solved.

I use interceptor to manipulate my request, here is the code:

```
@Injectable()
export class TokenInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(
    private authService: AuthService,
    private messageService: MessageService,
    private route: Router,
    private accountService: AccountService
    ) {}

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<unknown>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<unknown>> {
    const token = this.authService.getToken();
    if(token){
      request = request.clone({
        setHeaders: {
          Authorization: 'Bearer '+token
        }
      })
    }


    return next.handle(request).pipe(
      catchError((err:any) => {
        if(err instanceof HttpErrorResponse){
          if(err.status == 401){
            return this.handleUnAuthorizedError(request, next);
          };
        };
        return throwError(() => err)
      })
    );
  }

  handleUnAuthorizedError(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler){
    const apiToken: TokenApiModel = {
      token: this.authService.getToken(),
      refreshToken: this.authService.getRefreshToken()
    }
    
    this.authService.logout();

    return this.accountService.renewToken(apiToken)
    .pipe(
      switchMap((data) => {        
        this.authService.setToken(data.token);
        this.authService.setRefreshToken(data.refreshToken);
        this.authService.setId(data.id);
        request = request.clone({
          setHeaders: {
            Authorization: 'Bearer '+data.token
          }
        })
        return next.handle(request)
      }),
      catchError((err) => {
        return throwError(() => {
          console.log(err);
          
          this.messageService.add({severity:'warn', summary: 'Warn', detail: 'Token Expired, Please Login Again', life:3000});
          this.route.navigate(['/admin/login']);
        })
      })
    )
  }
}
```

So what i want to ask is, is there a way to make the parent component load data first, then the second component load data after the parent is done? i got an idea that is just make a timer for the child to run the API after 1 second, but i don't think that is a good practice.

Comment: Why not just let the parent component do all the thinking and pass the data needed by the child into it from there with an input? I think that if you have a problem with the back-end, that would probably be better fixed there. Maybe you could tell something more about that problem in your question.

Comment: @H3AR7B3A7, im using JWT that last 10 sec with refresh token that last 1 day, when i refresh the page, the moment 10 second pass, angular will fire a "refresh" request, but when 2 components run the APIs, it both detect that token is expire and BOTH fire the "refresh" request to the back end, and that is the problem, i only want 1 "refresh" request sent, so i'm thinking of just limit the flow of components that run, instead of both components run, if one of them run one after one, problem solved,

Comment: I agree with @H3AR7B3A7 - If your code is having this issue, sounds like you need to encapsulate the refresh logic and move it outside the components.

Comment: @Nieminen not possible, since i need that interceptor to manipulate my header to send token, i cannot move it outside my interceptor

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize Angular's EventEmitter and RxJS Subjects to achieve the desired behavior. In this approach, you'll emit an event from the parent component when the data loading is completed, and then the child components will start loading data upon receiving this event.

1. First, create a shared service:

```js
// shared.service.ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SharedService {
  parentLoaded = new Subject<void>();
}
```

2. Modify the parent component to use the shared service:

```js
// parent.component.ts
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { SharedService } from '../shared.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent',
  templateUrl: './parent.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./parent.component.css']
})
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private sharedService: SharedService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    // Load data and call APIs here
    // When data loading is completed, emit the event
    this.sharedService.parentLoaded.next();
  }
}
```

3. Modify the child components to listen for the event:

```js
// child1.component.ts
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { SharedService } from '../shared.service';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child1',
  templateUrl: './child1.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./child1.component.css']
})
export class Child1Component implements OnInit {
  private subscription: Subscription;

  constructor(private sharedService: SharedService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.subscription = this.sharedService.parentLoaded.subscribe(() => {
      // Load data and call APIs here
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    // Clean up the subscription
    if (this.subscription) {
      this.subscription.unsubscribe();
    }
  }
}
```

Repeat the same steps for Child2Component as well.

Now, the child components will wait for the parent component to finish loading data before they start loading their data.

I haven't run and tested this, but I think it should get you where you're wanting either way.

Comment: While this might work, it adds unneeded accidental complexity and is most likely just working around the underlying problem.

Comment: There is a small problem,  when i run child 1, i work fine, but the moment i change from chile 1 to child 2, the "this.subscription" on the child 2 doesn't run anymore, and when i switch back to child 1, it stop working too, it feel like when i run child 1, it only run once, then just stop running at that moment

Comment: That's because `ngOnInit` in the parent will run only once, since it is not destroyed.

Comment: @H3AR7B3A7 is there a way to fix it sir? tbh i don't really know how to solve it

Comment: If the parent component is aware of the child component changing, you could simply reset the 'loaded' value and make sure you send a new one.
You could also add simple boolean representation in addition to the 'subject', and check for that value when the child loads again. Without knowing a little more of your situation it's hard to make good suggestions.

Comment: i'm using JWT that last 10 sec with refresh token that last 1 day, when i refresh the page, the moment 10 second pass, angular will fire a "refresh" request, but when 2(or more) components run the APIs, it both detect that token is expire and BOTH fire the "refresh" request to the back end, and that is the problem, i only want 1 "refresh" request sent, so i'm thinking of just limit the flow of components that run, instead of both components run, if one of them run one after one, problem solved

Comment: @Nieminen and my coding style is similar to your example, but in the beginning, i haven't use your solution yet, and now, my coding is just like your example

Comment: You could alternatively add a 'debounce' to your requests for refresh, which would give you a single place to manage the solution.
Alternatively, you could make it so you only ask for a new token if a request fails authentication. For instance, you could make a call, if your token is no good any more, send back the appropriate status code, then have your logic request a new token, and resend the original request.

Comment: currently i'm using interceptor to manipulate my request, i'll give you the code of my interceptor, i'm not so sure how to code with your solution sir

Comment: it is done, you can check my interceptor from above sir

Comment: I'd hate to add additional complexity to it in a comment here. I would recommend moving your 'refresh' call outside the components into a service or something, and put a debounce and/or throttle on it so that it doesn't get called too often. Sounds like your primary issue is you don't want to keep generating tokens all the time - debounce/throttle aught to get you what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your suggestions and answers, but none of them work for me, so i think of another way, and it work for me, atleast for now:

**Please keep in mind that i use promise to make Api Call**

First i created a service:

```
@Injectable()
export class UserStoreService{
    private signal$ = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(null);    

    public getSignal(){
        return this.signal$.asObservable();
    }
    
    public setSignal(signal: boolean){
        this.signal$.next(signal);       
    }
    
}
```

Then at the parent component:

```
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private userStoreService: UserStoreService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    *some condition to execute back end call*   

    this.backEndApiCall()


  }

  backEndApiCall(){
    this.backEndApiCallService.method().then(
      res => {
        *logic here* 
        this.userStoreService.setSignal(true);
      },
      err => {
        console.log(err);         
      }
    )
  }

}
```

Then at the child component:

```
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private userStoreService: UserStoreService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    *some condition to execute back end call*   

    this.userStoreService.getSignal().subscribe(signal => {
      if(signal){
        this.backEndApiCall();          
      }
    })    
  }

  backEndApiCall(){
    *put your back end call here*
  }    
}
```